# Bookmarks in Places menu now open in Firefox instead of nautilus

Tags: nautilus, places, bookmarks

Fresh install 10.10 all my bookmarks mainly ftp and ssh bookmarks open firefox and show a web based file browser instead of spawning a nautilus window. have no idea what caused this never seen this before. This kills me on this machine to not be able to transfer/edit remote files right from my places menu.

Comment: I would open ubuntu tweak and go to File Type Manager and change the associated program there.

Comment: likely something in gconf gone wrong, I'll try to find it. just remind me.

Answer (score 3):

Right click a folder, go to Properties -> Open With, and change the associated program to Nautilus.  If there is a checkbox for "always use this program" make sure it's checked.

Comment: Are you sure this is feasible cause the 'open with' tab is not visible on folders on my gnome (2.30.2).

Comment: technically it is, but the option won't appear for folders, so it has to be changed from something else, like ubuntu-tweak (a 3rd party application).

Answer (score 3):

Open `/usr/share/applications` and find the entries:

**x-directory/normal**
**x-directory/gnome-default-handler**
**inode/directory**

make sure they equal to:

`nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`