# Ubuntu 13.04 opens disks and directories in the browser instead of in Nautilus

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, default-programs

for example, when I plug in my external hard drive, google-chrome opens `file:///media/atj/TOSHIBA%20EXT/`

When in sublime text Open Containing Folder opens the folder in the browser too.

Any clue to how I could get to the bottom of this ?

I have tried looking into /usr/share/applications/defaults.list but `inode/directory` is assigned to `nautilus-file-handler.desktop` like it should be. So I am really clueless

Comment: Have you tryed to install any othe File Browsers? (Dolphin, Pantheon-files (Elementary), Nemo) ? This not solution, but you can try...

Comment: Try the method used [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18684/bookmarks-in-places-menu-now-open-in-firefox-instead-of-nautilus).

Comment: I installed Ubuntu Tweak and all is fine and associated with Files. as for the other entries to add `x-directory/normal`, `x-directory/gnome-default-handler` & `inode/directory` I have added them to /usr/share/applications/defaults.list but no luck :/

Comment: Why ? I prefer staying with Nautilus if it is possible

Comment: Can somebody please refer someone, who might know a solution, to this discussion ? @Cameleono

Answer (score 0):

Enter in terminal this:

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/xdg-open
```

In opened file find this lines (near 532 line)

```
if [ x"$BROWSER" = x"" ]; then
    BROWSER=links2:links:lynx:w3m
    if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
        BROWSER=x-www-browser:firefox:mozilla:epiphany:konqueror:chromium-browser:google-chrome:$BROWSER
    fi
fi
```

Add in second "BROWSER" line *nautilus*:

```
if [ x"$BROWSER" = x"" ]; then
    BROWSER=links2:links:lynx:w3m
    if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
        BROWSER=nautilus:x-www-browser:firefox:mozilla:epiphany:konqueror:chromium-browser:google-chrome:$BROWSER
    fi
fi
```

This should help... maybe.

Comment: No, it did not work :/